# Proper Implementation of StyledEditorKit.UnderlineAction()

Tags: java, text, jtextpane

I'm using the StyledEditorKit in a project I'm working on. I've used the StyledEditorKit.BoldAction(), and the StyledEditorKit.ItalicAction(). Now I want to use the StyledEditorKit.UnderlineAction() as well.

I make the JButtons that they'll be used in:

```
    JButton bold = new JButton(new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction());
    tool.add(bold);
    JButton italic = new JButton(new StyledEditorKit.ItalicAction());
    tool.add(italic);
    JButton underline = new JButton(new StyledEditorKit.UnderlineAction());
    tool.add(underline);
```

They each have their own use where I setText(null) and assign an Icon to the button. Then when I try to use these buttons in an AbstractAction:

```
Action Bold = new AbstractAction("Bold", new ImageIcon("bold.png"))
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(bolded == false)
            {
                area.setFont(area.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
                bolded = true;
            }
            else
            {
                area.setFont(area.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
                bolded = false;
            }

        }
    };

Action Italic = new AbstractAction("Italic", new ImageIcon("italic.png"))
{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(italiced == false)
            {
                area.setFont(area.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC));
                italiced = true;
            }
            else
            {
                area.setFont(area.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
                italiced = false;
            }
        }
};

Action underline = new AbstractAction("underline", new ImageIcon("underline.png"))
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(underlined == false)
        {
            area.setFont(area.getFont().deriveFont(Font.UNDERLINE));
            underline = true;
        }
        else
        {
            area.setFont(area.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
            underline = false;
        }
    }
};
```

The first two AbstractActions work fine. The final one where I use

```
area.setFont(area.getFont().deriveFont(Font.UNDERLINE);
```

is not correct however. I have yet to find the actual implementation on oracle (am I looking in the wrong place maybe?), but I figure it is just how I am using 'UNDERLINE' that is incorrect. Simple answer I know. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand.  If you’re using StyledEditorKit.BoldAction, why do you need to write your own bold action?  What do you mean by “use these buttons in an AbstractAction”?  Actions do not use buttons, it’s buttons which use actions (as your first block of code is correctly doing).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Yeah that second half of code is completely unnecessary.

The StyledEditorKit that was called in the creation of the button was all I needed to get it working. When I was trying to implement that second AbstractAction, something was going on that wasn't happening in the other 2 AbstractActions (for what ever reason). 
I was under the impression I still needed to create another bold action in order to bold the text, but Java handles all of that automatically with the StyledEditorKit.